# Corner menu above gridview in android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, gridview, android-linearlayout

Hello everyone I need this thing I am attaching picture.. please help me out I am new in android. There is corner menu.. and there is gridview after open corner menu it should come above gridview.
I am referring one library called satellite menu in my xml here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:foursquared="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.infotech.zeus"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android.view.ext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu
            android:id="@+id/cornermenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            sat:closeOnClick="true"
            sat:expandDuration="400"
            sat:satelliteDistance="70"
            sat:totalSpacingDegree="90" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_main_gridView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >

    </GridView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_main_companylogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alerttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll_alertcounter"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="ALERTS"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <com.echo.holographlibrary.LineGraph
        android:id="@+id/linegraph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_main_companylogo" />

    <com.infotech.zeus.widget.SegmentedButton
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linegraph"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        foursquared:btnPaddingBottom="7dip"
        foursquared:btnPaddingTop="7dip"
        foursquared:cornerRadius="4dip"
        foursquared:gradientColorOffEnd="#2e6584"
        foursquared:gradientColorOffStart="#3b7d9e"
        foursquared:gradientColorOnEnd="#3a7ca2"
        foursquared:gradientColorOnStart="#4c9dc3"
        foursquared:gradientColorSelectedEnd="#FFAA00"
        foursquared:gradientColorSelectedStart="#FFAA00"
        foursquared:strokeColorr="#326e90"
        foursquared:strokeWidthh="1dip"
        foursquared:textStyle="@style/TextViewStyleHeaderButtonBlue" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_alertcounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_alertleftcount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_alertOF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="OF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#52A3D0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_alertrightcount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="WELCOME"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
        android:text="MR. TONY STARK"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Move the linearLayout containing the the satellite menu under your grid view in the xml. It will render the menu on top of the GridView

Comment: that means shall i remove my linearlayout?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Happy Coding.